# Android's SoundPool not playing any sound

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

I have tried everithing to make this work. The Android's SoundPool class is loading the .ogg audio file (tested), but it doesn't play.
For some strange reason i can't manage to get this working. I have followed many tutorials and forums on the matter, and still can't get it working.

Here's my code:

As Global variables:

```
 SoundPool soundPool;
 boolean ya = false;
```

On my Activity's onCreate:

```
   this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);    
   if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
                soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
                .setMaxStreams(15)
                .build();
    }else{
        soundPool = new SoundPool(15, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    }

    soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool sp, int sampleId, int status) {
            ya = true;
        }
    });     
    soundPool.load(this, R.raw.explosion_1, 1);
```

Finally, on the onClick method of one of my buttons:

```
public void instructions(View v){
    if(ya){
        soundPool.play(R.raw.explosion_1, 0.99f, 0.99f, 1, 0, 0.99f);
    }
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to play the sound, you need to pass in the `id` that you got from `load()` into `play()`.

```
int explosion = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.explosion_1, 1);
soundPool.play(explosion, 0.99f, 0.99f, 1, 0, 0.99f);
```

Comment: That was exactly my problem. Thank you very much. Solved.

Comment: also important to be sure that "explosion_1" melody have loaded with setOnLoadCompleteListener or there will be no sound. as loading is not instant.

Comment: In my case I can't play the sound, my activity has a camera scanner, maybe I need another thread? Because the same code I used in a simple activity and I can listen to the sound.

Answer (score 0):

I have played the sound from sd card using following code and it works for me.

```
private SoundPool mSoundPool;
private int mSoundID;

private boolean isLoaded = false;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Log.d(TAG, "Start Greeting View Activity...");

setContentView(R.layout.greeting_view_activity);
//mGiGiView = (GreetingWidget) findViewById(R.id.gigi_greet);
//mGiGiView.setOnTouchListener(this);

//Set default animation sound path.
String soundAnimUrl = "/gigi/anim/evening.ogg";

// get the Bundle out of the Intent.
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {

    // check to see if "soundAnimUrl" is in the bundle, if so then
    // assign it's value to animUrl if not, assign null to soundAnimUrl.
    soundAnimUrl = extras.containsKey("soundAnimUrl") ? extras
            .getString("soundAnimUrl") : null;
}

// Set the hardware buttons to control the music.
this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

// Load the sound.
mSoundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
mSoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
            int status) {
        isLoaded = true;

        // Play the sound when loaded
        play();
    }
});

mSoundID = mSoundPool
        .load(getFile(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC, soundAnimUrl)
                .getPath(), 1);

//Play sound from raw directory
// soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.greeting1, 1);      
}

private void play() {
// Getting the user sound settings
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
float actualVolume = (float) audioManager
        .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
float maxVolume = (float) audioManager
        .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;

// Is the sound loaded already?
if (isLoaded) {
    mSoundPool.play(mSoundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
    Log.d(TAG, "Played sound");
}
}






 @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {


switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.gigi_greet:
            play();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;

}   









 /**

 * Get File instance from sd card path.

 * 

 * @param deviceFolderPath

 *            - Pictures, Music, etc

 * @param dbFilePath

 *            - path stored in db (/gigi/anim/morning.ogg)

 * @return

 */

public File getFile(final String deviceFolderPath, final String dbFilePath) {

// Create full path
String picturePath = deviceFolderPath.concat(File.separator).concat(
        dbFilePath);

// Create file
File mFile = getExternalFilesDir(picturePath);

return mFile;
}
```